# get header name and ip in one line using nmap

Tags: awk, nmap

H;

am trying to get the header name and ip address in one line using Nmap, but I didnt find a good way to do this 
I tried : (using my router as example):

**I am using SSH**

```
nmap -sS -n -p80 192.168.2.1 --script=http-headers -T5 --min-rate 1000 --max-retries 0
```

Output:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1
Host is up (0.12s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
| http-headers:
|   WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="TD-W8901G"
|   Content-Type: text/html
|   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
|   Server: RomPager/4.07 UPnP/1.0
|   Connection: close
|   EXT:
|
|_  (Request type: GET)
```

what i am looking for as an output is :

```
192.168.2.1 => TD-W8901G or 
192.18.2.1:TD-W8901G
```

Regards

Comment: without your code, at this point it doesn't look like a programming question

Comment: I update my question please check

Comment: Please update your question again, so it is clear for everyone what you try to achieve. I can only assume that you are trying to parse the NMAP result with PHP based on the tags of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this with `awk`:

```
nmap ... | awk '/^Nmap/{ip=$NF} /realm=/{gsub(/"/,"",$NF);gsub(/.*=/,"",$NF);print ip,$NF;exit}'
```

That says... *"if the line starts with "Nmap", save the last field in variable `ip`. If the line contains "realm=", remove all double quotes and strip everything up to and including the equals sign. Print the `ip` and the last remaining field, then exit."*.

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for thank you so much